# Auto increment primary key in SQL Server (long unique code)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need add new column in to DB table but with auto increament (primary key). I could use this:

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

but this creates unique integers 1, 2, 3, etc But i would like create long uniques numbers exmpl: 0542365 or with letters A546980 it is posible?

Comment: integers won't commence with zero. If you need a larger range of integers use `BIGINT` instead of `INT`

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz any reasons just i would like use long

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to reliably and nicely do this:

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   AlphaID AS 'A' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `YourTable` without specifying values for `ID` or `AlphaID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `AlphaID` will contain values like `A0000001`, `A0000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.